# Python Jira authentication failed due to client network restrictions?

Tags: python, token, jira, jira-rest-api

I'am working on a python script to communicate with Jira and create an issue. I have successfully done that on a personal atlassian Jira software account but if I switch to work on a Jira reserved for a client I get errors. Add to that on the client Jira I'am unable to create an api token so I'am using my password instead as basic authentication.

The code I'am using is simple, so could anyone help with an idea how to move past this error.

```
    user_name = "my_username"
    ### I cannot generate a token due to client restriction #####
    api_token = "my_password_insteadOf_api_token"
    
    server = "https://asc.client_server.net/"
    
    jira = JIRA(basic_auth=(user_name, api_token), options={"server": server})
    
    # Test Data for Creating Issue
    test_data = {
        "project": "key_project",
        "summary": "test_summary",
       "description": "test_description",
        "issuetype": {"name": "Task"}
    }
    
    # Creating Test in Jira
    
    issue_key = jira.create_issue(fields=test_data)
```

Executing this code on the client environment give me this error

```
jira.exceptions.JIRAError: JiraError HTTP 401 url: client.url.toJira
```

Can anyone confirm my suspicition that under some circumstances there is no way to connect to Jira ?

Comment: Could you confirm what the hosting types of both your personal and client Jira instances are? Both Server, cloud or a mix?

Comment: @TomGionfriddo Both servers are cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Basic authentication using a username and password was depreciated for cloud in 2019. Unfortunately you must now you a supported method of authentication, such as basic authentication with API token, or Outh.

Deprecation notice: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/deprecation-notice-basic-auth-and-cookie-based-auth/

Comment: I used the basic authentication because this Jira I'am working on is restricted ! I cannot create my own token, I'am trying to contact the admin to see if he can create a token for me since I do not have the rights to it

Comment: @NabilZouita, Basic authentication with a password will NOT work on the Atlassian Cloud. Your only option will be to use authentication with an API token, or OAuth 2.0